# jQuery: Count occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: jquery, string, count

I have a string that is returned, that contains data separated by |'s.

I already have my script splitting by a '|', now I just need to count how many pieces of data are stored in the string, easiest way I see it would be to count the number of |'s in the string.

This is basically what's going on so far: http://jsfiddle.net/53ueL/

Greatly appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: you're never incrementing "i"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I it looks like you can just do:

```
$(".Count").html(TOElist.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about taking the length of that. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply get the length of the array you've split everything into?

```
$(".Count").html(TOElist.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53ueL/1/